# What's the best way to keep up to date on the latest news in the Rails world?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I read some of the answers on here I notice that some people are aware of upcoming changes to Rails syntax and I'm not sure how they find out about them. What's a good source of the latest information on syntax changes or updates to Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official [Riding Rails blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/) regularly details upcoming changes (usually titled "This Week In Edge Rails") and reviews what's changed when new versions are released.

Answer (score 4):

[A Fresh Cup](http://afreshcup.com) provides a number of links on nearly every weekday that includes information about changes to the Rails core and more.

[This Week in Edge Rails](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/edge) is another good resource for new checkins that might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can drink from the firehose and follow the [rails project on github](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master), and you may even get a rss feed for that.

Answer (score 1):

I like http://twitter.com/rails. They post links to the changes usually on the rails blog or elsewhere.